# Dynamically resize the width of the DropDownListFor only - MVC

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, dropdownlistfor

I am trying to have the DropDownListFor of each form group to dynamically resize. The first DropDownList always contains more characters than the other two. I am trying to get the other two to match the size of the first DropDownList.

Below is the original code:

```
<div class="form-horizontal my-5">
                <div class="form-group required">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">@FieldAliasUtilities.PerformanceManagement.PerformanceManagementAgreementYear</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        @if (Model.ContractId.HasValue)
                        {
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ContractYearId, Model.ContractYearSelectionList, new { disabled = "disabled" })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ContractYearId)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ContractYearId, Model.ContractYearSelectionList)
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group required">
                    <label class="control-label col-md-3">@FieldAliasUtilities.PerformanceManagement.AssessmentFrequency</label>
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                        @if (Model.ContractId.HasValue || Model.YearTypeId > 0)
                        {
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.YearTypeId, Model.YearTypeSelectionList, new { disabled = "disabled" })
                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.YearTypeId)
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.YearTypeId, Model.YearTypeSelectionList, new { onchange = "changeReviewFrequency(event);" })
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
                @if (Model.UserRole != Signify.HumanResources.PerformanceManagementV2.Contract.UserPageRoleList.User)
                {
                    <div class="form-group required">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DualApprove, new { @class = "control-label col-md-3" })
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            @if (Model.ContractId.HasValue || SettingUtilities.PerformanceManagement.ForceDualApproval)
                            {
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DualApprove, Model.DualApproveSelectList, new { disabled = "disabled" })
                                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.DualApprove)
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.DualApprove, Model.DualApproveSelectList, new { onchange = "changeDualApproveMessage(this.value);" })
                            }
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6" style="font-size: 12px; padding-top: 10px;">
                            <div id="dualapprove-on">* Only the @FieldAliasUtilities.PerformanceManagement.Manager will be able to create, approve and rate electronically.</div>
                            <div id="dualapprove-off" style="display:none">* Both @FieldAliasUtilities.PerformanceManagement.Employee and @FieldAliasUtilities.PerformanceManagement.Manager will be required to approve and rate electronically.</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                }

            </div>
```

I was able to set the width of the first DropDownList to auto which dynamically resizes it but I haven't been able to get the other two to match the size. Any help would be appreciated.